AREF pin on Arduino Uno R3
edit
So then, AREF can only output a voltage when used by the ADC, but not when used by the AC.
That is what I sense all your answers are pointing at, yet none has it black on white. My questions remains unmodified, below:

On the Uno R3, is the AREF pin supposed to present any voltage when default / bandgap voltage is set for the analog comparator?
With this code (analog comparator):
void initAC()
{
  ADCSRA = ADCSRB = ACSR = DIDR1 = 0; // also enables comparator
  ADCSRB |= (1 << ACME); // AIN1 from ADC mux
  ADMUX |= (1 << MUX0); // ADC1 input pin selected (PIN_VSENSE)
  ACSR |= (1 << ACBG); // AIN0 set to bandgap reference
                                          // voltage 1.1V
  //ACSR |= (1 << ACIS0) | (1 << ACIS1); // enable interrupr on rising edge;
  ACSR |= (1 << ACIE); // interrupts enable
  DIDR1 |= (1 << AIN0D) | (1 << AIN1D); // disable digital input buffers
                                          // for power saving
  PRR &= ~(1 << PRADC);                   // no power reduction ADC in order for
                                          // the AC to be able to use MUX input
  EEPROM.put(0x155, 0x5501);
}

When keeping the DMM probes on AREF / GND as the Arduino reboots I read some 10 mV steadily.
When touching the probes while the Arduino is running, I can read a decreasing voltage as through an RC group.
Tried with or without ACBG, same observation.
With this other code (analog digital converter):
{
 //power_adc_enable();          nah-uh!
 //power_usart0_enable();

 ADCSRA = ADCSRB = ADMUX = ACSR = DIDR0 = 0;
 ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);                  // power enable ADC
 ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIE);                  // enable interrupts
 ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS0);  // 250 kHz operation
 ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0);                  // 3.3V (AVCC) as voltage reference
 ADMUX |= (1 << ADLAR);                  // discard least significant 2 bits,
                                         // only read ADCH
 ADMUX |= (1 << MUX0);                   // ADC1 input pin selected (PIN_VSENSE)
 DIDR0 |= (1 << ADC1D) | (1 << ADC3D) | (1 << ADC5D);  // disable digital input
                                       // buffers for power saving, which is not
                                       // really needed given how the ADC is used
}

I was able to read a good 4.8V on the AREF pin. Swapped the Atmega328P chip on my Arduino board with another one - same behaviour.

After reading the answers I still don't understand why you try to read a voltage from an input.

On the ATmega328P (the microcontroller of the Arduino Uno), the AREF pin
is initially floating. If you try to read its voltage, you can get
basically anything.
As soon as you select an analog reference other than EXTERNAL, the
AREF pin gets internally connected to either the AVCC pin (if you select
DEFAULT) or the internal 1.1V reference (if you select INTERNAL).
This typically happens when you call analogRead() or, in your example
code, when you set the REFS0 bit of ADMUX.
Edit 1: As pointed out by JRobert in a comment, the section ADC
Voltage Reference of the ATmega328P datasheet is worth reading if
you consider using the AREF pin. Especially the warning in the third
paragraph.
Edit 2: Answering this new point:

AREF can only output a voltage when used by the ADC, but not when used
by the AC.

Whether or not it is being used by the ADC and/or the AC is irrelevant
to the behavior of the AREF pin. The only thing that matters is the
value of the REFS0 bit of ADMUX. The pin outputs a voltage if and
only if that bit is set. This can be clearly seen in this part of the
schematic of the ADC, from the datasheet:

When REFS0 is 1, the transistor circled in red connects the AREF pin
to either AVCC or the internal reference, as selected by the multiplexer
controlled by the REFS1 bit.
Note that you can change this bit without ever really using the ADC,
although that would probably be useless.

Also, see section 24.5 of the ATmega328 datasheet, "Changing Channel or Reference Selection" and especially 24.5.2 "ADC Voltage Reference". This subsection discusses the use of the AREF pin including a couple of warnings. Definitely worth a read!

@JRobert: Indeed! I added the relevant link to my answer.

You are supposed to supply an aref voltage to the aref pin. You supply your 5v reference to the aref pin, so that the ADC compares its input against the aref voltage.

As stated in the datasheet, section 1.1.8, the AREF pin is a reference voltage for the ADC. In other words it is an input.

AREF is the analog reference pin for the A/D converter.


From the datasheet:

23.5.2 ADC Voltage Reference
The reference voltage for the ADC (VREF) indicates the conversion range for the ADC. Single ended channels that exceed
VREF will result in codes close to 0x3FF. VREF can be selected as either AVCC, internal 1.1V reference, or external AREF pin.
AVCC is connected to the ADC through a passive switch. The internal 1.1V reference is generated from the internal bandgap
reference (VBG ) through an internal amplifier. In either case, the external AREF pin is directly connected to the ADC, and the
reference voltage can be made more immune to noise by connecting a capacitor between the AREF pin and ground. VREF
can also be measured at the AREF pin with a high impedance voltmeter. Note that VREF is a high impedance source, and
only a capacitive load should be connected in a system.
If the user has a fixed voltage source connected to the AREF pin, the user may not use the other reference voltage options
in the application, as they will be shorted to the external voltage. If no external voltage is applied to the AREF pin, the user
may switch between AV CC and 1.1V as reference selection.


As you can see from the above quote from the datasheet, once initialised, AREF is made available to you for measurement, and they recommend a capacitor to smooth out noise.
